# ¿Cómo disparar evento change de un option que se inicializara como checked? En VUE 2 JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web, component

buen día Comunidad.

Estoy tratando de disparar el evento change automáticamente para el option que se inicializará como Checked al terminar de renderizar mediante v-for todos los options de un Input Radio.

```
<div v-if="this.Field.type === 'radio'" class="form-check">
        <div v-for="(option, index) in this.Field.options" :key="index">
            <input type="radio" 
                :name="Field.name" 
                :value="option.value"
                @change="findChild($event)"
                checked> <!-- El último checked deberá disparar el evento change -->
                {{option.text}}
        </div>                           
    </div>
```

Por ejemplo, supongamos que cargo un input radio con 3 opciones contenidas en Field.options: Oro, Plata, Bronce, en donde inicialmente Bronce estará checked, por lo cual quiero que al terminar de renderizar el option Bronce me ejecute el método asociado al evento change sin que el usuario le de clic ya que sólo funciona hasta que el usuario lo cambia, pero no de un inicio (al terminar de renderizar los options).

¿Cómo le haría para que la opción que quede checkeada dispare el evento y ejecute la función indicada?

- No pongo todo el código para no confundirlos con fragmentos que no tienen relación.

Comment: Estás usando Vue 2? o Vue 3?

Comment: Vue 2 directamente con componentes .vue

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `mounted`, esta es una función que se ejecuta despues de que tu componente se ha renderizado y está listo para usarse y emites un evento:

```
// Componente hijo
export default {
  data() {
    // ...
  },
  mounted() {
    const mensaje = 'hola mundo'
    console.log("montado y enviando evento con valor: ", mensaje);
    this.$emit("my-event", mensaje);
  },
  methods: {
    // ...
  },
};
```

`this.$emit` viene en Vue y permite lanzar eventos desde el componente hijo al padre, y los eventos puedes puedes interceptar con `@my-event` o `v-on:my-event`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Fields @my-event="foo" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Fields from "./components/Fields";

export default {
  components: {
    Fields,
  },
  methods: {
    foo(msg) {
      // Imprime 'hola mundo'
      console.log("evento recibido: ", msg);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Así cuando se cree tu componente, se dispara la función sin que el usuario tenga que hacer algo.

[image: Edit new]

---

Puedes revisar los distintos ciclos de vida por los que pasa un componente [aquí](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)